# Some download troubles in Android

Tags: android, download

I use below code to download file:

```
URL u = new URL(one.getSrcPath());
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.setReadTimeout(10000);
c.connect();
int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + SavePath, FileName);
InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len1 = 0;
int finishbyte = 0;
long total = 0;
while((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
total += len1; //total = total + len1
f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
finishbyte++;
}
f.close();
```

I have two problems:
First, why my download task download fail very high frequency?
Second, if I want my download task resume from break point.
I have get the finishbyte.
How can I modify?

Comment: What is `finishbyte` representing? What are you trying to download? Are you stopping your program in the middle of a download (breakpoints?)?

Comment: You can use an AsyncTask to download a file, it's very easy to do !

Comment: Yes, I have already use AsyncTask. These part is in doInBackground. But I still don't know how to access that.

Comment: You declare the finishbyte in doInBackground methosd, so it's normal you don't access to this attribute in other class.
Declare the finishbyte in the class where do you want to get the value of finishbyte!

Comment: I declaration private int finishbyte as a global. In fact, I has get the correct finishbyte. But I don't know how to read start with the byte.

Comment: how big is your file? (also, for resuming, use the current file size. finshbyte does not carry any usable information here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finishbyte` both does not represent any information (except the number of calls to the `read` method, but certainly not the size of the downloaded file), and is not relevant, since you have written to a file and can use the File.length() method to know how much you got so far.

### To resume a download:

Open your file, check the size, request a range using the http header that is:

```
Range: <file.length()>-
```

(example, if you have downloaded 234 bytes:

```
Range: 234-
```

If the response code from the server is 206 Partial Content, you can append to your file, if it is 200, you have to overwrite your file (content have changed or Range is not supported)

Answer (score 1):

To start downloading a file starting with `finishbyte` position, you will have to use the [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) HTTP header. As for the failed downloads problem, it's probably a network issue or phone sleep issue, in which case you should check out the [wifi lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html)